# How to avoid duplicate records in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am fetching data from server in 2 steps .

First is fetch randomly 25 records from my table and show that records to user , now i have added a button . when user click on that button i have to show next 25 records from database but i need to sure that these records doesn't contains anyone which is already been displayed . How to do this in c#

Here is the code by which i get first 25 records

```
var records = context.couponservice.Query().Take(25).ToList();
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: How you fetch 25 records randomly?

Comment: Take returns records from the start of the sequence - it is not random.

Comment: Please comment the reason that why you vote down , so that i should keep that in mind for next time .

Comment: if you go with any of the `Skip()` and `Take()` solutions below, I'd strongly advise also adding an `OrderBy()`

Comment: @Smartboy Can you answer to my question?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan `var records = context.couponservice.Query().Take(25).ToList();`

Comment: @Smartboy Not clear! I don't see random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.Skip(pageSize * numberOfPages)` before the `.Take(pageSize)` to skip however many records/pages you don't want to show.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int position = 25; // Increase this for each page
var nextRecords = context.couponservice.Query().Skip(position).Take(25).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(i=0;i<noOfPages;i++)
{
   var records = context.couponservice.Query().Skip(i * 25).Take(25).ToList();
}
```

This will give you every time new records.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of which items you've already fetched. For example store the ID's in a List or something. Then collect only the items from your source whose ID is not in the List. From that result you can select 25 random items.

For example:

```
//Your datasource
var source = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1, "One"},
    {2, "Two"},
    {3, "Three"},
    {4, "Four"},
    {5, "Five"},
    {6, "Six"},
    {7, "Seven"},
    {8, "Eight"},
    {9, "Nine"},
    {10, "Ten"}
};

//The ID's of already fetched items
var taken = new List<int> { 2, 7, 3, 6 };

//Subset: all items that haven't been taken yet:
var temp = source.Where(s => taken.Contains(s.Key) == false);
```

From 'temp' you can select random elements now and add the ID's of those items to the List 'taken'.